# Create UIBarButtonItem with fixed size and with custom icon

Tags: ios, uibarbuttonitem

I've created navigation bar like picture below

[image]

The "drop" button is a custom system UIBarButtonItem. It's contained in Right Bar Button Items and its area was expanded.

I want its size fit the image I set, like Compose button on the right.

Comment: you can put as static in the navigation bar.

Comment: @Jay Nothing change if I set I width with fixed number

Comment: it's default functionality of uitabbarbutton.

Comment: @Jay Please excuse my ignorance, do you mean there is no way but using custom view instead navigation bar

Comment: you can add bar button using programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

```
public func setCustomButton() {

    let btnSearch: UIButton = UIButton(type: .custom)
    btnSearch.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 25.0, height: 25.0)
    btnSearch.setImage("Your image", for: .normal)
    btnSearch.addTarget(self, action: #selector(yourActionName(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    et btnBarButtonSearch: UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: btnSearch)
    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [btnBarButtonSearch]
 }
```

hope, it will help you.